# JSON structure for an iOS 9-10 silent push notification

Tags: ios, json, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

We are developing an app which could receive remote push notifications. We just understand that there are two types of notifications, “*normal*” and silent.
We want to know the JSON structure of a silent notification with message.

```
{
"notification_type":2,
  "aps":
         {
             "alert":"Message de la notification", 
             "content-available":1,
            "badge":1,
             "sound":"default"
         }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For silent push notifications we omit the `alert`, `badge` and `sound` (that are not used in silent pushes) keys and then the notification is not displayed, but the handler is called. The json should look like this:

```
{
  "aps":
         {
             "content-available":1,
         }
}
```

You can send extra contents with the notification too, so your app will know what to do:

```
{
  "aps":
         {
             "content-available":1,
         }
  "example-action": "example"
}
```

Comment: But, there is no message tag in a silent notification ? or a silent notification is not a message type of notification ? I'm pretty lost with the purpose of a silent notification.

Comment: The purpose of a silent notification is to execute something on background inside the app. For example, you want the app to download an updated image you show on a screen, then you send a silent push notification with an image URL so your app will handle the push and download it on background. You won't display this notification to the user, then you don't need the message